# Can't Provide Qualified String with Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm trying to follow the sample [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/java/dagger/example/android)

I have already used Dagger2 with the AndroidInjector successfully but now I was experimenting the new `DaggerApplication` and `DaggerAppCompatActivity`.

I get the error:

> Error:(5, 1) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or
>   from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

I don't think that the new Dagger classes are causing the issue.
If I remove the `@DeviceModel` in *BuildModule.kt* the code compiles.

Any suggestion?

Here the code:

The *AppComponent.kt*

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        MainActivitySubComponent.MainActivityModule::class
))
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()
}
```

The *AppModule.kt*

```
@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(MainActivitySubComponent::class))
class AppModule {

}
```

The *BuildModule.kt*

```
@Module
class BuildModule {
    @Provides
    @DeviceModel
    fun provideModel(): String {
        return MODEL
    }
}
```

The *DeviceModel.kt*

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class DeviceModel
```

The *MainActivitySubComponent.kt*

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(BuildModule::class))
interface MainActivitySubComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>()

    @Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(MainActivitySubComponent::class))
    abstract class MainActivityModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
        internal abstract fun bind(builder: MainActivitySubComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
    }
}
```

The *MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    @DeviceModel
    lateinit var model: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d(model, model);
    }
}
```

The *App.kt*

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<App> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `@field:DeviceModel` for your String. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103894

Comment: @dewey it worked thank you. If you post it as an answer I'll approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Dagger with Kotlin objects, we have to consider how Kotlin actually creates properties in the JVM.

```
@Inject
@DeviceModel
lateinit var model: String
```

With a property like this, [Kotlin compiles three Java elements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties): a private backing field, a getter, and a setter (due to `var` rather than `val`). With no further clues as to your intent, Kotlin places your `DeviceModel` annotation on the getter.

The solution is to specify that the field is to be annotated with `@field:[annotation]`.

```
@Inject
@field:DeviceModel
lateinit var model: String
```

You may also need to use `@JvmField` to make the backing field public for Dagger, which would preclude using `lateinit`, and of course, require you to initialize the String.

```
@Inject
@field:DeviceModel
@JvmField
var model: String
```

**Update**: I'm not sure why, but in my testing, the field was private, which is why I suggested `@JvmField`. According to the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields), the field should be created with the same visibility as the setter.

---

Note that in general, Kotlin is smart enough to apply custom annotations with `@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)` to the backing field, but this would prevent you from also using it on the `fun providesModel`

Comment: You saved my life with this `@field:DeviceModel` or `@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)`. Thanks!!!